# Eclipse can't tell android device version

Tags: android

So, I've managed to get Eclipse detecting my Android device for debugging, but for some reason it can't detect the Android version. This means that I can't launch my app to the device.

[image: Device Chooser message]

Anyone know why this is? (And before anyone says it, I've tried restarting everything)

EDIT: It's a HTC Desire device, and I've never had this problem before (i.e. its worked before)

Comment: Driver problem maybe?

Comment: Could be, I just don't see why that would break it overnight.

Comment: I had this problem with a bad cable, exactly the same. When I switched to another one it worked. It is a long shot, but you could try it.

Comment: I've also had bad cables. I've also had the phone just suddenly reject ADB completely until I factory reset it.

Comment: Tried another cable and got the same problem. Gunna have to try a factory reset I guess. Thanks for your help guys :)

Answer (score 0):

its problem with New ADT 21.1 and if you dont have install platform 17 than you have this problem..install new ADT and update ADB and restart pc.done